# Validation errors display of every command in page header (Spring 3)

Tags: java, spring, validation

I want to display a div with all error messages in my page header. I know how to do for for a single command eg:

```
<spring:hasBindErrors name="<my_command>">
  <div class="error_box">
    <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors.allErrors}">
      <spring:message message="${error}"></spring:message><br />
    </c:forEach>
  </div>
</spring:hasBindErrors>
```

but I would like to have global div for every command So I wouldn't need to repeat nearly same code. Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only idea I have is:

```
<%
Enumeration en = request.getAttributeNames();
while(en.hasMoreElements()) {
    String attr = (String)en.nextElement();
    if(attr.startsWith("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult")) {
        %>
        <spring:hasBindErrors name='<%= attr.substring(attr.lastIndexOf(".")+1) %>' >
            <div class="error_box">
                <c:forEach var="error" items="${errors.allErrors}">
                    <spring:message message="${error}"></spring:message>
                    <br />
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
        </spring:hasBindErrors>
        <% 
    }
}
%>
```

Maybe one day I will get a better answer :)